# Removing node from NodeList of XML Doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, parsing

I am trying to remove certain nodes from XML doc if they exist in below array:

```
 const removeNodesDataMap = [
    'Source',
    'ProductCode',
    'ProductCategory',
    'PublicationDateTime',
    'ArticleID',
    'Author'
 ];
```

I tried doing it using xmldom npm package and using removeChild method as follows:

```
function removeXmlNodes(str) {
    const xmlValue = new DomParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
    removeNodesDataMap.forEach(node => {
        const rNode = xmlValue.getElementsByTagName(node)[0];
        if (rNode) {
            const sNode = xmlValue.removeChild(rNode.parentNode);
        }
    });
    const serializer = XMLSerializer.serializeToString(xmlValue);
    return serializer;
}
```

However, serializer still contains all the nodes. What is the best way to remove nodes based on if they match with whats in above array?

Example of XML:

```
<Source>ABC</Source>
<ProductCode>77</ProductCode>
<ProductCategory>Performance</ProductCategory>
<PublicationDateTime>2019-03-06  17:04:5.000</PublicationDateTime>
<ArticleID>123254</ArticleID>
<Author/>
<records>
<record>some record stuff that I actually want to return along with node</record>
</records>
```

Expected output is:

```
"<records><record>some record stuff that I actually want to return along with node</record></records>"
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to bit weird with your xml when it is missing a root. I kind of can fix your issue but I need the xml content wrapped in a root. The major change is remove by calling node.ParentNode.remove(node)

```
const { DOMParser, XMLSerializer } = require('xmldom');

const removeNodesDataMap = [
  'Source',
  'ProductCode',
  'ProductCategory',
  'PublicationDateTime',
  'ArticleID',
  'Author',
];

function removeXmlNodes(str) {
  const xmlValue = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<root id="root">${str}</root>`, 'text/xml');
  removeNodesDataMap.forEach(node => {
    const rNode = xmlValue.getElementsByTagName(node)[0];
    if (rNode) {
      rNode.parentNode.removeChild(rNode);
    }
  });
  const serializer = new     XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlValue.getElementById('root'));
  return serializer;
}

const input = `
<Source>ABC</Source>
<ProductCode>77</ProductCode>
<ProductCategory>Performance</ProductCategory>
<PublicationDateTime>2019-03-06  17:04:5.000</PublicationDateTime>
<ArticleID>123254</ArticleID>
<Author/>
<records>
<record>some record stuff that I actually want to return along with node</record>
</records>
`;

console.log(removeXmlNodes(input))
```